# Why does SSL not work inside a build jar?

Tags: java, ssl, javafx, jar

I have a small project in which i want to use TLS 1.3.

As main example i used this respo: https://github.com/williamswhy/SSLSocket

This is my server:

```
Server() {
    SSLServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    SSLSocket socket = null;

    try {
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(3122);
        MariaDB mariaDB = new MariaDB();
        new Thread(mariaDB).start();
        while (true) {
            socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new ClientConnection(socket,mariaDB)).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "sslserverkeys");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
    new Server();
}
```

My Client uses the following class:

```
try {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "sslclienttrust");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");

    //DO NOT CHANGE THIS
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
    sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket("localhost", 3122);
    System.out.println("Successfully initialized connection");

    try {
        this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Successfully opened ObjectOutputStream");
    } catch (IOException var4) {
        var4.printStackTrace();
        try {
            this.out.close();
        } catch (IOException var3) {
            var3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have a sslclienttrust file in the root folder of my client and sslserverkeys in the root folder of my server. I'm coding in IntelliJ Ultimate with Maven and the connection works like a charm in it.
But when i build a .jar (using maven-shade-plugin) I get an exception.

The Server throws the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:889)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1251)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1893)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1802)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(ObjectOutputStream.java:252)
    at ClientConnection.<init>(ClientConnection.java:21)
    at Server.<init>(Server.java:20)
    at Server.main(Server.java:36)
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1052)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:82)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:356)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1052)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.flush(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:268)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedProducer.onProduceFinished(Finished.java:783)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedProducer.produce(Finished.java:671)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1252)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1188)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:851)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:812)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:445)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:423)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1475)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1381)
    ... 9 more
```

The client throws the following:

```
the last modified time is: Mon Sep 28 00:44:21 CEST 2020
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|Thread-4|2020-09-29 24:55:10.430 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:334|Reload the trust store
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|Thread-4|2020-09-29 24:55:10.468 CEST|TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:70|SunX509: skip default keystore (
"throwable" : {
  java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:794)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:241)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1472)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(TrustStoreManager.java:390)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:336)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:56)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:49)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:281)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineInit(SSLContextImpl.java:94)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(SSLContext.java:313)
        at connection.ServerConnection.connectToServer(ServerConnection.java:204)
        at connection.ServerConnection.run(ServerConnection.java:42)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
  Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:792)
        ... 12 more}
```

At first i thought this has something to do with wrong pathing, so i tried a couple of ways mentioned on sof. But the error, that the password is incorrect or the keystore is tampered confuses me. The password cannot be wrong, because it is working in the IDE.

Why does the SSL work in my IDE, but not inside the .jar
I saw some threads about SSL not working at all, but not like this.

Answer (score 4):

System property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` requires that you pass a file in, and that file must.. exist.

entries in jars are file-like, **but not files**, so you **cannot use a truststore file packed inside a jar file**. That kinda explodes the point of a jar in the first place, and is why this isn't 'working' - you're running the jar from someplace where the working dir isn't proper. In general passing a relative entry (something that doesn't start with `/` or `C:\` or whatnot) to `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` is never going to work in the hands of end users and requires careful scripting by the ops team if you try to deploy that on your own servers.

To load a trust store from any random source, such as 'a resource 'file' that is in the same place my class files live; look in the jar file if you have to', check [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/java/example/1420/loading-truststore-and-keystore-from-inputstream).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a more common, besides easier way to implement what i want to achieve ?

Comment: I linked to it, no? Normally, the server has some standard certificate, e.g. from lets-encrypt (something any webbrowser would understand), and then you don't need a custom trust store on the java client at all.

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly fine. My question is, if this is the common way to authenticate TLS1.3 or do it otherwise, perhaps with a Webserver? I had a lot of struggle with the setup and didn't find that much documentation about it.